# Employee App with Java EJB andJAX-RS and Server Faces

Tags: java, jsf, ejb

I would like to create an employee administration tool with JAVA Entreprise Java Beans and RESTful web-services(JAX-RS).

The intention is that you have an endpoint for example Administration/v1/emp where you can POST an new employee with name etc.

So far this works and I can send a POST request with SOAPUI for example.

Now I would like to create an UI with Java server faces and/or PrimeFaces. I have seen that I can create managed beans for that and use this managed beans to invoke methods on my entreprise java beans(businees logic)
So far so good. 
But in my application I have now two servlets in my web.xml like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/v1/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
      <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>org.se.bac.service.RESTApplication</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

And that works, if I call a resource like /v1/emp the resteasy servlet will process the request and if I call the index.xhtml file the jsf servlet works.

But what I want to do is that I want to build a graphical user interface above the resources - so I want to call /v1/emp in the browser and then the user should see for example a list or form (as defined in the xhtml file)

But now I get an json or xml representation (of course) if I call the resource /v1/emp and to get my list defined in the list.xhtml file I need to call list.xhtml in the browser

How can I achieve my concern above to call a resource /v1/emp and to get the UI xhtml page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's the rules, that are used by servlet container to route request to the specific servlet ([source](http://docs.roguewave.com/hydraexpress/3.5.0/html/rwsfservletug/4-3.html)):

1. The container will try to find an exact match of the path of the request to the path of the servlet. A successful match selects the servlet.
2. The container will recursively try to match the longest path-prefix. This is done by stepping down the path tree a directory at a time, using the ’/’ character as a path separator. The longest match determines the servlet selected.
3. If the last segment in the URL path contains an extension (e.g. .jsp), the servlet container will try to match a servlet that handles requests for the extension. An extension is defined as the part of the last segment after the last ’.’ character.
4. If neither of the previous three rules result in a servlet match, the container will attempt to serve content appropriate for the resource requested. If a “default” servlet is defined for the application, it will be used.

So, you can for example use different URIs for your API and for your pages. For example define your servlets like this:

```
...
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/api/v1/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
...
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/v1/*</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So the idea is you need to divide requests. And you need to be more specific in that as container is using only requested URL to definde who will handle it. Also you can define your Faces Servlet as default servlet and then from your `index.xhtml` always be specific with routes to other pages using extension.

Comment: Hello, 

Thanks for your answer, that means that I should never call a resource directly from the web-browser like /api/v1/emp but call just for instance index.html and offer maye a form with input fields where you can created a new employee. 
And in the managed bean function - for example action="#{dataBean.create(...)}" - take the parameters which were entered in the form and call inside this function with - I don't know getRequestURL() (...) my resource /api/v1/emp
but not directly from the browser? 

Is it possiblto use java server faces and rest (JAX-RS) in one application?

Comment: why you need REST API? You have another clients like mobile clients? from web-browser you will get page with `v1/emp` if faces servlet will handle that request. From managed bean you don't need to call URL you can directly inject your rest controller with JAX-RS annotations and just use it as is. They are in the same controller so there will be no problem with that.